# Windows 10 Notification from desktop APP : OnActivated event

Tags: c#, wpf, uwp, win-universal-app, windows-10-universal

I create a desktop app c# where i use some references :

```
using Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.Notifications;
using System.Windows;
using Windows.ApplicationModel.Activation;
using Microsoft.QueryStringDotNET;
```

And where i added some reference related to UWP application :

```
- Windows.System
- Windows.UI
- Windows.data
- Windows.Foundation
- Windows.ApplicationModel
```

Then i created a simple procedure to create and show my toast notification with the followin code :

```
 private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {


    var toastContent = new ToastContent()
    {
        Visual = new ToastVisual()
        {
            BindingGeneric = new ToastBindingGeneric()
            {
                Children =
    {
        new AdaptiveText()
        {
            Text = "Surface Launch Party"
        },
        new AdaptiveText()
        {
            Text = "Studio S / Ballroom"
        },
        new AdaptiveText()
        {
            Text = "4:00 PM, 10/26/2015"
        }
    }
            }
        },
        Actions = new ToastActionsCustom()
        {
            Inputs =
{
    new ToastSelectionBox("status")
    {
        DefaultSelectionBoxItemId = "yes",
        Items =
        {
            new ToastSelectionBoxItem("yes", "Going"),
            new ToastSelectionBoxItem("maybe", "Maybe"),
            new ToastSelectionBoxItem("no", "Decline")
        }
    }
},
            Buttons =
{
    new ToastButton("RSVP", "action=rsvpEvent&eventId=63851")
    {
        ActivationType = ToastActivationType.Foreground
    },
    new ToastButtonDismiss()
}
        },
        Launch = "action=viewEvent&eventId=63851"
    };


    Windows.Data.Xml.Dom.XmlDocument xmldoc = new Windows.Data.Xml.Dom.XmlDocument();
    xmldoc.LoadXml(toastContent.GetContent());
    var toast = new ToastNotification(xmldoc);

    toast.Activated += OnActivated1;

    // Create the toast notification
    //var toastNotif = new ToastNotification(xmlDoc);

    // And send the notification
    ToastNotificationManager.CreateToastNotifier("Test").Show(toast);
```

Now my problem is that i don't know how to retrieve the item i selected in the list :-(

I created an procedure based toast.Activated event :

```
void OnActivated1(ToastNotification sender, object e)
{
    var toastActivationArgs = e as ToastNotificationActivatedEventArgs;


}
```

With this event, i can retrieve the argument (to know the button i clicked on) but getting the UserInput thanks to the class "ToastNotificationActivatedEventArgs" seems to be not possible...
Do you know if it's possible ? Is it a limitation of using reference UWP in a desktop app ?

Thank you very much !
Vincent

Answer (score 4):

If you're building a Win32 Desktop app using the Desktop Bridge, you currently cannot use inputs and selection boxes in your toast, as there's no way to retrieve the input.

If you're building a normal Win32 app, you must set up a COM server to handle activation, which will include the inputs that the user selected. [This quickstart explains how to set this up for normal Win32 apps](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/tiles_and_toasts/2015/10/16/quickstart-handling-toast-activations-from-win32-apps-in-windows-10/). Plus, this will also allow your toasts to persist in Action Center, so if the user missed the popup, they can still access your toast from Action Center.

Comment: I have just tested the COM server solution (c# project was available on download) and same behaviro : no information returned concerning listbox :-(

Comment: The input data is returned in the `NOTIFICATION_USER_INPUT_DATA[]` array. I've just updated the GitHub code sample to include a listbox in the toast and the selection is displayed in the app when the user selects something and clicks Answer.

Answer (score 0):

thank you for your answers.

The issue i have with my sub OnActivated :

```
void OnActivated1(ToastNotification sender, object e)
{
    var toastActivationArgs = e as ToastNotificationActivatedEventArgs;


}
```

is that the "e" object is recocgnized as a ***Windows.UI.Notifications.ToastActivatedEventsArgs*** and not as "***ToastNotificationActivatedEventArgs***" from **Windows.ApplicationModel.Activation** (where the properties Kind, UserInput.. should be very useful for me to get the content of selected item).

In my OnActivated1 sub, the ***var toastActivationArgs*** value equals to **null** because it cannot be converted to **ToastNotificationActivatedEventArgs**.

During my test the e.arguments equals to string "***action=rsvpEvent&eventId=63851***" but there is no XML returned. This is the only property available of the object e. (but this is useful to get the button where i clicked on)

I'm going to check the link from Andrew Bares to try to setup a COM server but i can see that's in c++ language..

Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

Just simply use this code according to [Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/design/shell/tiles-and-notifications/send-local-toast?tabs=desktop):

```cs
// Listen to notification activation
ToastNotificationManagerCompat.OnActivated += toastArgs =>
{
    // Obtain the arguments from the notification
    ToastArguments args = ToastArguments.Parse(toastArgs.Argument);

    // Obtain any user input (text boxes, menu selections) from the notification
    ValueSet userInput = toastArgs.UserInput;

    // Need to dispatch to UI thread if performing UI operations
    Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(delegate
    {
        // TODO: Show the corresponding content
        MessageBox.Show("Toast activated. Args: " + toastArgs.Argument);
    });
};
```

Answer (score -1):

The `ToastNotificationActivatedEventArgs e.Arguments` should be an xml string with what you need ready to parse.

First look at the string and see if it has what you need. Then go about using XMLReader or something to parse it.

Could you post the string you get?